# Не работает скрипт скролинга при подключении fullpage или как работает scrolling в fullpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, fullpage

Товарищи, вроде простая задача, но что-то не получается. Нужно добавлять и убирать class при прокрутке. Если убрать функцию fullpage, то всё работает как надо.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
  if (sc) {
    $("#nav").addClass("scrolled");
  } else {
    $("#nav").removeClass("scrolled")
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 3em;
  height: 100vh;
}
.scrolled {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/dev/src/fullpage.js"></script>


<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

Но с функцией fullpage ничего не работает, даже в консоль ничего не выдаёт.

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
    if (sc > 10) {
        console.log("down");
        $("#nav").addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $("#nav").removeClass("scrolled")
        console.log("up");
    }
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 3em;
  height: 100vh;
}
.scrolled {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/dev/src/fullpage.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

***Нашёл ещё один способ:***
В функцию `fullpage` добавляем `scrollBar: true`, так же в css прописываем html{overflow: hidden!important} и можем использовать скролинг и параллакс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что при использовании fullpage.js прокрутки как таковой не происходит, а изменяется свойство `transform` для указанного блока, соответственно событие `scroll` не происходит, для отслеживания прокрутки там есть callback `onLeave`

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
    if (destination.index > 0) {
      $("#nav").addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
      $("#nav").removeClass("scrolled")
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 3em;
  height: 100vh;
}
.scrolled {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/dev/src/fullpage.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Нашёл в API, сижу изучаю :)